# Do the ellipsis/ellipses (...) replace commas?

Tags: commas, ellipses

There is contradicting information on how to use the ellipsis/ellipses (and contradicting information on what its exact name is called--but that's irrelevant) so I'll ask. And I know it's mostly a matter of style, no universal rule, but:

Do the ellipsis/ellipses replace a comma? Specifically when the ellipsis/ellipses indicate a pause and not an ommission.

> This is the correct way of using it, ... isn't it?

**(The spaces between the ellipsis/ellipses is only to avoid confusion between trailing off)**

> But I prefer it like this ... but is that enough to show that this would be after a comma?

Currently, I've already read many smaller mentions of the above but nothing concrete enough to mention, which is why I ask.

Comment: I agree that there is no answer approaching a definitive one in the 'duplicates' I've checked in. Personally, I'm not afraid to double punctuation where I think it adds clarity (or occasionally as a pragmatic usage, to signal an exclamation say), but not elsewhere. This can be complex with nested lists where you wish to indicate which level of set  has just ended with a comma or a semicolon. But I'm not happy that this is the perfect solution. But then I've never found one. // With your example, I see no need for or advantage in using the comma....

Comment: The ellipsis both offsets the break in flow (facilitating reading)  and signals the (extended) pause-for-thought perfectly adequately, so the 'don't over-clutter' rule-of-thumb kicks in.